# String interpolation for built-in functions

Tags: php, function, internal, string-interpolation

I have something like this in PHP

```
$file = "$dir/" . basename($url);
```

`basename` is a built-in function. Is there a way I can use string interpolation syntax for concatenation instead of `.` syntax?

For member functions of a class, this works:

```
$file = "$dir/ {$this->someFunc($url)}";
```

How do I similarly specify internal functions in quoted strings? Just learning.

Comment: Not cleanly, interpolation works on variables; but function calls aren't the same as variables

Comment: You could create a class wrapper that would do the function call for you

Comment: Alright. I expected there has to be a syntax since something like `"{$x->y()}"` works. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkBaker: Assigning the function name to a variable works, though. But you really shouldn't write that kind of messy code

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - True. I'd been thinking of something like: `class functionCaller {
    public static function caller($function, ...$args) {
        return call_user_func_array($function, $args);
    }
}

$fc = new functionCaller();

$file = "$dir/{$fc->caller('basename',$url)}"`

Comment: Using sprintf() Would be another, somewhat cleaner, alternative

Comment: @MarkBaker: my first idea was to use a caller-class, too (possibly with a `__call` method to expose all/certain global functions for easy string substitution, but that would end up being messy, needlessly complex and slow, compared to a clean `printf` + direct function calls

Comment: @MarkBaker seeing your code, do you need to instantiate a class even to call its static method in PHP?

Comment: @nawfal: Not for statics, no. and as far as the approach I hinted at, implementing a `__callStatic` wouldn't require you to create an instance either... but really: if you don't know how to use them already, spend some time learning the format specifiers for the `*printf` functions, it's well worth it for things like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like so:

```
$foo = 'bar';

$func = "strtoupper";
echo "test: {$func($foo)}";
//or for assignments:
$path = sprintf(
    '%s/%s',
    $dir,
    basename($file)
);
```

[example here](https://eval.in/465412)

But really, you shouldn't: it obfuscates what you're actually doing, and makes a trivial task look a lot more complex than it really is (debugging and maintaining this kind of code is a nightmare).
I personally prefer to keep the concatenation, or -if you want- use `printf` here:

```
printf(
    'Test: %s',
    strtoupper($foo)
);
```